# Location service issue in iphone app GPS arrow does not disapper

Tags: ios, iphone, gps

I have an app which use Location Services.
Code as follows:

Version 4.0.0

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{ 

  if (nil == locationManager)
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
//some other code
}
```

Once app goes in background location Icon in status bar **does not disapper**.

verison 4.0.1

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{     
  if (nil == locationManager)
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
//some other code
}
```

Now questions:

1) After updating existing app (4.0.0) to new version 4.0.1 Location Icon stop showing in status bar once app goes in Background.

However ever in some devices (specially iOS6) the icon won't disapper. But after reseting location service by DEVICE: Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy

New app versin 4.0.1 icon does disappear after app goes in the background mode for 10 sec.

I would like to know why this happen? Why on some iOS or device user have to Reset location service.

verison 4.0.2

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{     
  if (nil == locationManager)
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
 [locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
//some other code
}
```

2) If app update from 4.0.0 to 4.0.2 directly I dont need to Reset Lcoation.
The location icon will disapper after app goes in the background mode for 10 sec. How come this is different logically from question1.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked you project settings `Background Modes`?

Try clicking your project in the solution panel, go to the `Capabilities` tab and select the `Background Modes`.

Then select the modes appropriate for your app (I guess you need to turn on atleast `Location updates`)

Comment: I partially found answer. In version 4.0.0 (above code) I have startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges . According to Apple If you start this service and your application is subsequently terminated, the system automatically relaunches the application into the background if a new event arrives.

Answer (score 0):

To make the icon disappear, you app has to stop the location service, especially when the app uses background mode:

Call:

```
stopUpdatingLocation
```

when going into background. Then after some seconds, the icon will disapper.

For significant Location mode it is different.
You app always will be restarted when a sig Loctaion change was detected, and your app is not yet running. Therfore to make the icon disapper, you have to stop the significant loctaion service.

Comment: thanks for you comment Alex However I would like to know why 4.0.0 to 4.0.1 App did not work as desire!! If I have delete app (4.0.0) and all relavant data should have been deleted!! why do I need to reset location service on some iOS (6)!! Hope I have explain correctly!